# Eclipse 2021-12 doesn't recognize maven variables on mouse hover

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have the `Eclipse 2021-12 j2ee`, `m2e_apt` plugin, `Spring Tool Suite` using `java8` and if I try to read the value of a maven variables like this:

```
<value>${some}</value>
```

I didn't see nothing.. those worked with previous version of Eclipse..

They made release continuosly but a thing is improved and another one is get worse..

Is there some way to make it work? It's pretty useful.

------------------------ UPDATE ----------------------

[image]

the mouseover action over `${agevolo.cliente}` doesn't show nothing, nothing happens

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Not reproducible in the current Eclipse 2022-03 (containing m2e 1.20).